# Prove that $mn$ divides $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a \in G$, $b\in G$, and $\vert a\vert =m$, $\vert b\vert=n$, $\gcd(m,n)=1$, if $a^k=b^k$ for some integer $k$, prove that $mn$ divides $k$.  Any idea to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What happens when you raise each side of the equation $$a^k=b^k$$ to the power of $m$? To the power of $n$?

Comment: they will be equal to e

Comment: That is right! So if, for example, you raise both sides to the power of $m$ you have $e=b^{km}$. What can you say about $km$?

Comment: n divides km, since gcd(m,n)=1, so n divides k. similarly, m divides k, but how can we conclude mn divides k given m|k, n|k, gcd(m,n)=1?

Comment: Very good. It is generally true that if two coprime numbers divide a third number then their product also divides the third number. I believe one way you might show this would be to use prime decomposition.